# Getting only the values base on a list

Tags: excel, vba

My code below gives me a result with a unique customer codes base on Calculation sheet. However, I want to get my result base on the list that I have in Solution Sheet. Also want to run the macro within Solution Sheet. Any help will be appreciated.

Calculation Sheet

[image]

Solution Sheet

[image]

```
Sub cTotals()

Dim arr, arr2, arr3
Dim Calc As Worksheet: Set TS = Worksheets("Calculation")
Dim Sol As Worksheet: Set Sol = Worksheets("Solution")
Dim x As Long, i As Long, a As Long, c As Long, ct As Long
Dim GIVMM As Single, MSU As Double, Cases As Double
    
    
arr = Calc.Range("B2:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
arr2 = arr
With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If Not IsMissing(arr(x, 1)) Then .Item(arr(x, 1)) = 1
Next
arr = .Keys
End With
ReDim arr3(1 To UBound(arr) + 1, 1 To 7)
c = 1: ct = 1
For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
    For a = 1 To UBound(arr2)
        If arr2(a, 1) = arr(i) Then
            arr3(i + 1, c) = arr(i)
            arr3(i + 1, c + 1) = ct
            ct = ct + 1
            GIVMM = GIVMM + arr2(a, 5)
            arr3(i + 1, c + 2) = GIVMM
            MSU = MSU + arr2(a, 6)
            arr3(i + 1, c + 3) = MSU
            Cases = Cases + arr2(a, 7)
            arr3(i + 1, c + 4) = Cases
        End If
    Next
    ct = 1: GIVMM = 0: MSU = 0: Cases = 0
Next
Sol.Range("B6").Resize(UBound(arr3, 1), UBound(arr3, 2)) = arr3

End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you use formulas like `SUMIFS`?

Comment: I just put here a sample of my data but I am working with 200,000+ rows of data that needs to be executed fast using dictionary.

Comment: You can code to evaluate everything with SUMIFS and then overwrite formulas with values. Even with 200.000 rows of data it should take seconds, no need of dictionary

Comment: Will try that. How about running my macro with a button in Solution sheet.

Comment: If i had this task I would take unique values for customer_code + prod_code and after that add Sumifs function for every row with `Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs()` wth two conditions ( you can VBA it :) ). Why customer_code+prod_code ? You will be able to easly tell what/when/by who is order created + how many orders were created.

Comment: *How about running my macro with a button in Solution sheet* Got to Solution Sheet, insert a button from Developer Tab and assign the macro you code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Data Structures (Array, Collection, Dictionary)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CalculateData()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Calculation"
    Const scCol As Long = 2
    Dim sCols() As Variant: sCols = VBA.Array(4, 6, 7, 8)
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Solution"
    Const dfRow As Long = 6
    Const dcCol As Long = 2
    Const dColumnOffset As Long = 1
    Dim dOffsets() As Variant: dOffsets = VBA.Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Write the values from the source range ('srg') to an array ('sData').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    
    ' Write the unique source values to the 'keys' ('sString')
    ' of a dictionary ('sDict'). Its 'items' ('sDict(sString)') will hold
    ' a collection of all the (source) rows ('r') where the 'key' appeared.
    
    Dim sDict As Object: Set sDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    sDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sString As String
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 2 To srCount
        sString = CStr(sData(r, scCol))
        If Len(sString) > 0 Then
            If Not sDict.Exists(sString) Then
                Set sDict(sString) = New Collection
            End If
            sDict(sString).Add r
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Write the values from the destination lookup column range ('dlrg')
    ' to a 2D one-based (one-column) array ('dlData').
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dcCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dlRow - dfRow + 1
    
    If drCount < 1 Then
        MsgBox "No data in the destination column.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dlrg As Range: Set dlrg = dws.Cells(dfRow, dcCol).Resize(drCount)
    
    Dim dlData() As Variant
    
    If drCount = 1 Then ' one cell
        ReDim dlData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): dlData(1, 1) = dlrg.Value
    Else ' multiple cells
        dlData = dlrg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Write the results to the destination array ('dData').
    
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(sCols)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = cUpper + 1
    
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim dDict As Object: Set dDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sItem As Variant
    Dim sValue As Variant
    Dim dString As String
    Dim c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To drCount
        dString = CStr(dlData(r, 1))
        If Len(dString) > 0 Then
            If sDict.Exists(dString) Then ' found in the dictionary
                For Each sItem In sDict(dString) ' loop through the rows
                    For c = 0 To cUpper
                        If c = 0 Then ' unique count
                            sString = CStr(sData(sItem, sCols(c)))
                            dDict(sString) = Empty
                        Else ' sum
                            sValue = sData(sItem, sCols(c))
                            If VarType(sValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
                                dData(r, c + 1) = dData(r, c + 1) + sValue
                            'Else ' is not a number; do nothing
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next c
                Next sItem
                dData(r, 1) = dDict.Count
                dDict.RemoveAll
            ' Else ' not found in the dictionary; do nothing
            End If
        ' Else ' vbNullString ('""'); do nothing
        End If
    Next r
        
    ' Write the values from the destination array to the destination range.
        
    With dws.Cells(dfRow, dcCol).Offset(, dColumnOffset)
        .Resize(drCount, cCount).Value = dData
    End With
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data calculated.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```